# It says I haven't asked any questions, but I have.

Tags: support

I placed a question at math.stackexchange.com, and it was answered.  It was a request for a resource.  I got some good resources from it.  It was great.  Of course, I didn't bookmark the resources....  Now the site's saying I haven't asked any questions.

The only conclusion I can come to is that maybe it was deleted.  What should I do?

Comment: I see no deleted questions associated to your account. Are you sure you didn't ask it using a different account?

Comment: If you remember a keyword or two from your question (or from an answer) you can type it into Google together with site:math.stackexchange.com and it may come up.

Comment: @zev yeah, it's possible that I asked on a different site in the stack exchange.  Thank you, for the help.  Gerry, thank you.